# Delete in change event produces error 28 stack overflow

Tags: excel, vba

Without the If construct to change a null value produced by deleting the value in a cell in the range to 0, the following code produces an error 28 Stack overflow.

The explanations I have found for the worksheet change event indicate, that delete will trigger the change event; however, they do not indicate that DEL will produce a null target.value and result in the error.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells As Range    
    If Target.Value = "" Then    
        Target.Value = 0        
    End If

    MsgBox (Target.Value)  

    Set KeyCells = Range("C3:C10") ' Error occurs here
End Sub
```

What is the most efficient way to ensure that deleting a value in the Range will not result in a null value and produce this error?

Comment: a) Are you checking **any** cell on the worksheet or should target be restricted to a range? b) what is the point of setting a range var if you just exit the sub immediately after?

Answer (score 0):

I keep saying the same three things over and over.

1. Disable events if you are going to make changes to the worksheet or the worksheet_change will try to run on top of itself.
2. Handle situations where Target is more than a single cell.
3. Add some error control; at least enough to re-enable event handling.

Code rewrite:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim t as range, KeyCells As Range  

    on error goto safe_exit
    for each t in target  
        If t.Value = "" Then 
            application.enableevents = false   
            t.Value = 0        
        End If
        MsgBox (t.Value)  
    next t   

    Set KeyCells = Range("C3:C10")

safe_exit:
    application.enableevents = true
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your excellent suggestions.  As it turns out, I have found my problem is elsewhere.  In other code Del dosen't change the target value to null and the code works fine.  I believe now a setting  of mine somewhere is causing the problem.  Your suggestions are still helpful top someone learning and seeing them for the first time,  Regards John